# Spark dropduplicates but choose column with null

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table that looks like that:

```
+---------+-------------+--------------+-----------+--------+--------------+--------------+
| cust_num|valid_from_dt|valid_until_dt|cust_row_id| cust_id|insert_load_dt|update_load_dt|
+---------+-------------+--------------+-----------+--------+--------------+--------------+
|950379405|   2018-08-24|    2018-08-24|   06885247|06885247|    2018-08-24|    2018-08-25|
|950379405|   2018-08-25|    2018-08-28|   06885247|06885247|    2018-08-25|    2018-08-29|
|950379405|   2018-08-29|    2019-12-16|   27344328|06885247|    2018-08-29|    2019-12-17|<- pair 1
|950379405|   2018-08-29|    2019-12-16|   27344328|06885247|    2018-08-29|              |<- pair 1
|950379405|   2019-12-17|    2019-12-24|   91778710|06885247|    2019-12-17|              |<- pair 2
|950379405|   2019-12-17|    2019-12-24|   91778710|06885247|    2019-12-17|    2019-12-25|<- pair 2
|950379405|   2019-12-25|    2019-12-25|   08396180|06885247|    2019-12-25|    2019-12-26|<- pair 3 
|950379405|   2019-12-25|    2019-12-25|   08396180|06885247|    2019-12-25|              |<- pair 3
```

As you can see I have some duplicated rows in my table and they are only different regarding `update_load_dt` being empty or with a date.

I would like to drop duplicates in my dataframe in such a way:

```
cable_dv_customer_fixed.dropDuplicates(['cust_num',
'valid_from_dt',
'valid_until_dt',
'cust_row_id',
'cust_id'])
```

but I would like to keep the row with more information. 
By that I mean I would like to keep the row `where update_load_dt <> ''`

Is it possible to modify dropduplicates() function so that I can choose which row from duplicates to choose? or is there some other (better) way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would go about this, F.max() will do what you want and keep the row with the highest value. (on date col max() keeps latest date entry if there's multiple).

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
key_cols = ['cust_num','valid_from_dt','valid_until_dt','cust_row_id','cust_id']
w = Window.partitionBy(key_cols)

df.withColumn('update_load_dt', F.max('update_load_dt').over(w)).dropDuplicates(key_cols)
```

I work with 1billion+ rows and this is not slow. 
Let me know if this helped!

Comment: The problem here is that in case of multiple valid `update_load_dt` the max value will be taken. It works, but not only on NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use window functions for that. With Big Data, it can be slow, though.

```
import pyspark.sql.function as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df.withColumn("row_number", F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(<cols>).orderBy(F.asc_null_last("update_load_dt"))))
.filter("row_number = 1")
.drop("row_number") # optional
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @Topde's answer, if you create a bolean column that checks if the value that you have present in your column is the highest one, you only need to add a filter that will only eliminate the duplicate entries with the "update_load_dt" column as null

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.function as F
key_cols = ['cust_num','valid_from_dt','valid_until_dt','cust_row_id','cust_id']
w = Window.partitionBy(key_cols)

(df.withColumn('update_load_dt', F.when(F.max('update_load_dt').over(w), True).otherwise(False))
.filter(F.col('update_load_dt'))
.distinct()
)
```